# Can a Google Map be populated with data contained in a WordPress Category Archive?

Tags: google-maps, wordpress

Is it possible to insert a Google Map into a WordPress category archive that would read all of the data in the places on a category page and create markers for them?

I have a directory site where each place on my site has been geocoded.  Places are individual posts.  They are organized into categories by city.  The output of the each category page is a list of all the places for that city.

My URLs look like this:
example.com  (Homeapge)
example.com/city (City Archive Page - shows a list of all places in my db for that city)
example.com/city/famous-restaurant (Place Detail Page - shows all data about a specific place in my db)

I want to create a map once that I can put on top of example.com/city and it would show markers for each listing I have in my db for a specific city.  I don't want to have to create individual maps for each city.

I found [this tutorial](http://geochalkboard.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/reading-xml-files-with-the-google-maps-api/) but it would require an XML dump of my db on the fly.

Are there better ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You'd use a combination of the Google Maps API and get_posts()

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers

and

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Though, the posts will have to have the latitude and longitude stored with them.  Otherwise, you'll probably need to use another part of the google maps API to look the places up...